# Mobile GPRS connection and OSI layer

Tags: networking, mobile, gprs, osi

When using a GPRS connection from a mobile device, how do the different OSI layers map into the components on the device/mobile network ?

Answer (score 1):

**OSI Layers**

1. Application Layer
2. Presentation Layer
3. Session Layer
4. Transport Layer
5. Network Layer
6. Data Link Layer
7. Physical Layer

**Realisation in GSM**

1. Application Layer
2. Presentation Layer
3. Session Layer
4. Transport Layer

**Layer 5** involved in below activities

5.1 Call Control

5.2 Mobility Management

5.3 Radio Resource Management

This layer is responsible for the management of an established connection and of the associated activities in the radio network

**Layer 6** - Entity responsible for the secure transmission of data messages between the mobile and the base station.

6.1 Segmentation / Concatenation

6.2 Acknowledgement

**Layer 7** - Physical Characteristics of Medium of transmission

7.1 Forward Error Correction

7.2 Channel Encoding

7.3 Modulation

Comment: The layer numbers you have listed are reversed. Layer-1 is the physical layer, while layer-7 is the application layer. This is important to get right because when someone starts talking about layer-1, you will be referencing the wrong layer.

Comment: @RonMaupin, Thanks Ron. I agree.